(Barber's paradox) Is it mathematically correct to write : "$(a,b)\not\in X \implies (b,a)\in X$ implies $(a,a)\in X$"?
$(a,b)$ is a point in $Y$. $X$ is a subset of $Y$.
Condition 1: $(a,b)\not\in X \implies (b,a)\in X$
Is it mathematically correct to write: Condition 1 implies $(a,a)\in X$?
Here is the tentative proof by contradiction. Suppose $(a,a)\not\in X$, then $(a,a)\in X$. So we conclude $(a,a)\in X$.
I find this is incorrect because of the Barber paradox. What do you think?

Assuming it’s quantified over all $a,b$, yes it does imply that. The issue isn’t with the implication, but whether a set $X$ with this property can exist.

There is nothing wrong with that logical statement.   For example it's true for relation
$$
\{(1,1)\} \text{ on the set } \{1\}   .
$$
In fact it's true for the relation $X = S \times S$ on any set $S$ since the hypothesis $(a,b) \not \in X$ is always false.
It's also true for the relation on the integers given by
$$
(a,b) \in X \text{ just when } a \le b.
$$
The barber paradox starts with "Everyone is shaved by someone and there is barber who shaves everyone who does not shave himself".  If you write that out formally then your argument shows that can't happen. Note that there must actually be a barber. If everyone shaves himself there's no contradiction.
